# How to avoid multiple helper implementations like __indexOf() with grunt-contrib-coffee

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I have a `Gruntfile.coffee` that has a [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) configuration like this:

```
coffee:
  compile:
    files:
      'public/assets/application.js': [
          'multiple/files' #, ...
      ]
    options:
      bare: true
```

The Problem is, that it generates multiple implementations of helper methods like

```
    var __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };
```

How to make it recognize that these implementations are already compiled?

## Update 1

The reason is obviously that the compiled JavaScript gets concatenated *after* it got compiled. It could be avoided if the CoffeeScript would be concatenated *before* compiling it. If this is not a configuration option of [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) that I'm missing, I'll submit an issue on github.

So the question that remains is: how to concatenate the CoffeeScript before compiling it, to avoid multiple helper implementations?

## Update 2

There is a workaround, which involves manual concatenation of the source files with the `concat` task. This requires a temporary file, that can then be compiled from CoffeeScript to JavaScript. It is mentioned in the [issue I created](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/issues/51).

In future, tasks will be able to pass their stuff as buffers to each other (see the [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/issues/51)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of grunt-contrib-coffee-0.6.1 this works with the `join` option:

```
coffee:
  compile:
    files:
      'public/assets/application.js': [
          'multiple/files' #, ...
      ]
    options:
      bare: true
      join: true # concatenate coffee files before compiling. default is false
```