# Coffeescript can not access class because of scope

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

I have two classes **StepsForm** and **BiblioForm** and I want Steps form to **extend** BiblioForm, but when I try it with the code below the console says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: BiblioForm

**StepsForm Class**

```
(($) ->

    class StepsForm extends BiblioForm

        ...

    form = new StepsForm;

) jQuery
```

**BiblioForm Class**

```
(($) ->
    class BiblioForm

        ....

    basicBiblioForm = new BiblioForm

) jQuery
```

I use grunt to compile and put these classes together like this

```
coffee: {
  compile: {
    files: {
      'lib/js/tome-references.js' : [
        'lib/coffee/biblio-form.coffee',
        'lib/coffee/steps-form.coffee',
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

I just want to note that I need to use jQuery in both classes.

When I delete the first and last line in each class the extending functionality work, but then I don't have access to jQuery.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Since you already have compilation step you could configure bundler (webpack or browserify) and make it resolve dependencies for you. `$ = require 'jquery' \n module.exports = class BiblioForm ... ` and `$ = require 'jquery' \n BiblioForm = require './biblio-form.coffee' \n module.exports = class StepsForm extends BiblioForm `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jQuery is a dependency, make it explicit in your classes.

```
class BiblioForm
  constructor: (@$) ->

  doSomething: =>
    @$("#foo").bar()

class StepsForm extends BiblioForm
  constructor: ($) ->
    super($)

  doAnything: =>
    @$("#baz").hide()
```

and instantiate it like

```
biblioForm = new BiblioForm(jQuery)
stepsForm = new StepsForm(jQuery)
```

It is also good idea to [concatenate coffee files before compiling them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15481998/878514) to avoid other visibility problems.

Comment: Thanks that helps, but is there any way to use just "$" and not "@$", because it kinda feels weird.

Comment: You can write `this.$` which is the same. Personally, I would make the jQuery globally accessible. This is against OOP principles but hey, one can treat jQuery as a JS extension.

Comment: I can use "jQuery" in my class but I can't the "$" sign

Comment: Try [`$ = jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) somewhere at the beginning of your application.